# Combine FullCalendar and Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, fullcalendar, asp.net-ajax

I had included Jquery Fullcalendar in my MVC View but I encounter some problems to deal with all the interactions.
Asp.Net Mvc is made to make things simpler by separating presentation, view and logic and with Jquery Fullcalendar I can't use this power.
For example: 
I have specific datas whose are specific to the current month.
If I want to edit, delete, create these datas, in Asp.net it's normally really simple but the fact that they are specific to the current month (which we can switch with an arrow) makes the things incredibly hard to manage. I have to deal with a lot of ajax requests in order to perform all the basic actions.
How would you proceed to deal with that problem ?
What I do for instance is to use a knockout view model where I store all these datas and perform actions on them, but I feel that it's not the proper way.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I've integrated FullCalendar on one app of mine once. What I did was handle all the callbacks in the FullCalendar and call MVC actions assynchronously to update the model and maintain the consistence between backend and frontend.

Your're right, there are a lot of callbacks that need to handle but I think that's the wait to do it. That isn't a problem with MVC or FullCalendar, is just a matter of integration between two things, and FullCalendar is a big plugin, with a lot of functionality.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm doing.
I handle dayClick, eventClick, viewRender(month loading) and make a ton of ajax requests in order to keep things synchronized but my JS is going bigger and bigger.

Comment: And it comprises the goal of MVC which is a separate of concern.

Comment: You're confusing two things.
One thing is separation of concern, another is the size of the application or plugin.
When you integrate FullCalender with MVC you're not violating the separation because the pattern is still applied.
The 'View' is still presenting the content to the user, while the 'controller' is been called to update the 'model'.
The thing here is that are a lot of callbacks to handle, but the pattern isn't violated, because is not a matter of '1 call to action instead of n calls to action', it's a matter of separation of responsabilities, and this still intact.

Comment: You're right. But to a certain extent, we're using the view to store data which is not its responsability.

Comment: How did you proceed to store you're mvc objects in the view ? I am here using knockout js and created a view model that store the mvc objects but it's not that secure cause the user could access to all my objects properties.

Comment: That time I didn't have any secure concerns, so I just used some objects in KnockoutJS like you, and posted back this model when the users have done the updates.